# Save the jQuery Ajax Response in global variable to send it to another page (no local or session storage)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call and save the response in the global variable which can be accessed in another page.

Here is my reusable AJAX function -

```
function coAjax(url, data, handleData) {
    if(url != null && url != ''){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {
            handleData(result);
        },  
        error: function(e){  
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}};
```

I am using that function on a button click on Page 1 -

```
$('#buttonOnPage1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url ="example.com";
    var data = JSON.stringify(dummyData);
    coAjax(url, data, function(result){
        console.log(result);
        window.location.href = "page2.jsp";
    }); 
}
```

I wish to access the `result` of the ajax without the `local` and `session storage` used which can be used for in the `page2.jsp`. I can't state the reason for not using local and session storage. Please help.

Comment: Do you have enough control over how they get to page 2 to make sure that you include GET params in the url you can read from?

Comment: It is not possible to do it with a variable.... Only way to do it would be a GET request (query string) or a POST request and the other page would have to look at the request and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will be available to the page2.jsp as: <%= request.getParameter("json_data_id")%>

If data = ({data:[{ name: "John", pet: "cat" },{name: "Doe", time: "dog" }]}), then the "json_data_id" will be for example: data[0][name]

Answer (score 0):

You can encode `encodeURIComponent` your data and pass it as query parameter to new page url and access using `window.location.search` and decode `decodeURIComponent` there.